# Laravel eloquent search functionality

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm currently creating a search functionality on my index blade file.

I have different users that have different stores per area.

my User model:

```
    function area() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Area');        
}

function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}

function reports() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Report');
}

function stores() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Store', 'App\Area');
}
```

}

Area model:

```
   function reports() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Report');
}

function stores() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Store');
}

 function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Store model:

```
    function district() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\District');
}


function cluster() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cluster');
}
function city() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
}

 function area() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Area');
}
```

I have managed to make the functionality work on admin account (where in you can see all stores) by:

```
function index(Request $request) {
    if($request->has('search')) {
        $stores = Store::whereHas('city', function($query) use($request) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%');
    })->orWhereHas('cluster', function($query) use($request) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' .$request->search. '%');
    })->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' .$request->search. '%')
      ->orWhere('store_no', 'like', '%' .$request->search. '%')->paginate(10);  

    } else {
        $stores = Store::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    }

    return view('/stores.store_list', compact('stores'));
```

what I want to do on user accounts is:

```
function index(Request $request) {
    if($request->has('search')) {
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        $query = $request->search;
        $user = User::find($id)->stores()->where('name', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')->paginate(10);


    } else {

        $id = Auth::user()->id;
       $user = User::find($id)->stores()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    }

    return view('/stores.store_list', compact('user'));

}
```

I'm having an error when searching:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `stores` inner join `areas` on `areas`.`id` = `stores`.`area_id` where `areas`.`user_id` = 6 and `name` like %houston% and `stores`.`deleted_at` is null)

can anyone point me on the right direction and let me know what i'm missing here? Thank you!

Comment: Prefix query builder table names. For example, try with: `$user = User::find($id)->stores()->where('stores.name', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')->paginate(10);`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment! You're a life saver. I have managed to make it work thanks to you! All the best, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have error such is

```
Column 'some_column_name_here' in where clause is ambiguous...
```

it means that there is complex query associated with more tables of which at least two those have same table name in their structure and that table name is used in complex query (in some ON, WHERE...) in this case `WHERE` as error states. 
You always can use `table_name.column_name` {table name dot column name} syntax to point syntax at exact table meant ([ambiguous](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=en&text=ambiguous)).

Comment: thanks for the info. I thought I was already accessing what's inside the store table by querying  User::find($id)->stores cheers! Thanks again!